# How to create login condition and core data table values can't be stored twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I have some problem on my project. Login form of my mobile app attached to PHP Login service and performing well too.I am also added core-data. In core data table, user id text field and password text field of login form and their data store in local DB, work properly.

But I want, when user login at the first time, then the values are stored in local database value store and when the user log out from here and second time user login with same login id and password at that time database cannot record twice.

Clearly, I want values can't be stored twice. please suggest how it works.

## MY CODE

```
- (IBAction)btn_action:(id)sender {
   if([[self.tx_userid text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.tx_password text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
    
    } 
   else {
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MYURL"]];
    
    
    //create the Method "GET" or "POST"
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    
    //Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
    NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"loginid=%@&loginpassword=%@",_tx_userid.text,_tx_password.text, nil];
    
    
    
    //Check The Value what we passed
    NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);
    
    //Convert the String to Data
    NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    //Apply the data to the body
    [request setHTTPBody:data1];
    
    //Create the response and Error
    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    
    //  if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
    {
        
        
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                  JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error:&error];
        
        int success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
        
        
        if(success == 1)
        {
            // stored in local DB
            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
            
            NSManagedObject *newDevice = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Loginuser" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            
            [newDevice setValue:self.tx_userid.text forKey:@"userid"];
            [newDevice setValue:self.tx_password.text forKey:@"password"];
            
            NSError *error = nil;
            // Save the object to persistent store
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
        } else {
            
            NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
            [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
        
    }
    
}




NSLog(@"app dir: %@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);


  }

 - (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                    message:msg
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
alertView.tag = tag;
[alertView show];
 }
```

Comment: you mean to say if user login once the then relevant data saved to db then again he login after logout, that time you dont want to enter the same user data inside db ?

Comment: @vaibhav Yes you are right. but how to do this?

Comment: see my ans if suits ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions for your problem.

**Solution 1:**
 You can clear the user id and password from coredata whenever the user logs out. So when the user logs in next time, it won't add the same user id again. (I prefer this solution)

**Solution 2:**
If you really don't want to clear the user id when the user logs out, you can check just before login whether the user id is already present in core data or not. If it's already there, you don't need to add it again. You can overwrite any parameter if you want (But I basically don't prefer this one because you don't need to save any details in coredata if you have a backend server and database to keep track of the users already logged in.)

**Critical issue in your code:**
Don't save information like passwords in coredata as it lacks privacy. If you really want to save the password, you can save it in the keychain. Lot of third party classes are available which does that(Eg: https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain)

**Edit**

First, you need to fetch all the user ids from the coredata

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"LoginUser"];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error != nil) {

   NSLog(@"Coredata fetch failed");
}
else {
   BOOL userPresent = NO;
   for(NSManagedObject *user in results){
      if([[user objectForKey:@"userid"] isEqualToString:self.tx_userid.text])
         userPresent = YES;
   }
   if(userPresent == YES)
     //user is present in DB
   else
     //new user
}
```

Comment: I dont want user logs out time clear data in DB. I want to store only user id not required password stored in DB.

Comment: This user id helps through make a switcher functionality.

Comment: If you don't want to clear data, proceed with the 2nd approach. Every time user logs in, fetch all the entries from your coredata entity and check whether it contains the newly entered user id. If it exists, you can use the same object, otherwise create a new one

Comment: Please explain some code because i tried to many times but did not work properly. and if else condition do not work properly. i don't know please explain some code. how to do this.

Comment: are you there, please help

Comment: Its working good. thank you so much to give Precious time. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

First you check login id is not same that all stored login id when user login .
When it is same then user allow to login without store data otherwise first store data and after allow to login.

Comment: please explain some code. because i tried many times but did not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch user data like `userId` and check if that `id` is already present inside database so don't save again user data inside local db this will solve your data redundancy. Take `emailId` as `userId` its a unique for all users.

Get the current `userId` to check and create a global `BOOL` variable to indicate whether you need to save user data or not.

Code for fetch data:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"entityName"];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (error != nil) {

   //Deal with failure
}
else {
    for(NSManagedObject *user in results){
        if([[user objectForKey:@"userid"] isEqualToString:currentUserId])
            userPresent = YES;    // global bool variable
    }   
    if(userPresent == YES)
        // no action needed 
    else{
        // call method to save user data 
        [self saveUserInfo];  
    }
}

-(void) saveUserInfo{
    // code here to save data inside db
}
```

Work with the result array now it has fetched data inside.

Comment: Please explain how to check condition and how to check pass object already stored or not?

Comment: Your answer in that else condition i stored a new data in DB?

Comment: what is userPresent. Mr. Arun solved my problem. thanks to give your Precious time. :)

Comment: `userPresent` is the global variable where you declare inside dec part of your class.. welcome.